# no function clause matching erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I just picked up Erlang and I ran into a simple problem, but I have not been able to fix it or find anything about it. I'm trying to define a module that checks if an `atom` is in a given list. I entered the list through the Erlang shell like this:

`veggies:veggieMember([cucumber,tomato,potato],tomato).`

But I always get `exception error: no function clause matching`

Maybe I misunderstood the basics, but here is the module code I'm trying to do:

```
-module(veggies).

-export([veggieMember/2]).

veggieMember(veggieList,query)->
case lists:member(query, veggieList) of
    true->veggieList;
    false->[query|veggieList]
end.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Binding in erlang starts with a capital letter. So it should be:

```
-module(veggies).

-export([veggieMember/2]).

veggieMember(VeggieList,Query)->
case lists:member(Query, VeggieList) of
    true -> VeggieList;
    false -> [Query|VeggieList]
end.
```

In your example it didn't work because there is no matching function clause. Atom `veggieList` doesn't match list `[cucumber,tomato,potato]` and atom `query` doesn't match atom `tomato`.

The error itself, it one of the [standard errors](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/errors.html). It means you have made a call to function and that none of the function clauses (separated by `;`) matched.

Comment: `Binding in erlang starts with a capital letter`, why capital though? entering capital require additional effort of pressing shift key :)